# MySQL 5.7 No Longer Returns Meaningful Error Messages

Tags: mysql, errors

When I select from a table that doesn't exist:
[image: Missing table]

When I select a nonexistent column from an existing table:
[image: Missing column]

I used to receive meaningful error messages (ie 'Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'column' in 'table''), but now only the error number is returned, without an explanation of what happened. This happens to everyone that connect to this particular MySQL database.

Does anyone know how I can fix this without reinstalling MySQL? I'm running MySQL 5.7.9 Community Server (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: As per the error codes coming out sensibly and I can see that from [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html). Error: 1146 SQLSTATE: 42S02 (ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE) Message: Table '%s.%s' doesn't exist Error: 1054 SQLSTATE: 42S22 (ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR) Message: Unknown column '%s' in '%s' What client you're using to connect? Can you confirm this from the cli?

Comment: what you get in error log file?

Comment: What version of what UI are you using?

Comment: Already answered - forgot to mark my post answered :) Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the MySQL error log, I noticed the following line: `Can't find error-message file '\share\errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.` That file did not exist, however `\share\english\errmsg.sys` did exist. I found out from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102875/mysql-5-5-starts-and-then-instantly-stops) that this error message is not entirely accurate, since MySQL does not actually look in the `\share\` directory - it looks in the `\share\*YOUR LANGUAGE*\` directory.

I looked in my my.ini and discovered that I had a line that said `basedir =` (that's all that the line said - there was no path after basedir). I'm not entirely sure how that configuration came to be, but I commented out that line and everything works great now!

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, the problem is that the lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql/English/ (English with an uppercase 'E') while the folders at the time of installation were all 'english' with a lowercase 'e'.

For me, the error output was limited to the error codes only. No error text whatsoever. Changing the directory (either in the startup options or renaming to 'E' is what fixes it.)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to setup correctly the lc-message-dir into your mysql.cnf :

```
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql/english/
```

And error messages will be back ;)