# Mysql Server always throwing unknown error

Tags: mysql-5.7

Sorry for the bad formatting since its the first time

When i try to delete a row which has a foreign constraint, i'm expecting the Mysql server to give me the constraint key and the table to which it's related to but all i get is only this message "Unknown error 1451".

mysql server version : 5.7.26 (linux)

```
CREATE TABLE `detailmenu` (
  `detailmenu_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `detailsubprg_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`detailsubprg_int_id`),
  KEY `FK_detailsubprgmtb_1` (`subprg_int_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_detailmenu_1` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_id`) REFERENCES `menu` (`menu_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=81 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When i try to delete a row from this table which has a constraint i expect the Mysql server to atleast give me the constraint key which is 'FK_detailmenu_1' or the child table reference but all i get is "Unknown error 1451" without any additional information. Is there any configuration issue? This issue does not come in windows machine.

Comment: *Error number: 1451; Symbol: ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED_2; SQLSTATE: 23000* - *Message: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (%s)* - *InnoDB reports this error when you try to delete a parent row that has children, and a foreign key constraint fails. Delete the children first.*

Comment: I understand that but the mysql server is supposed to give the message as "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`tablename`, CONSTRAINT `FK_constraintname` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_int_id`) REFERENCES `detailmenu` (`detailmenu_int_id`))" not as "Unknown error 1451" . Due to this i'm unable to get the constraint name for the exception

Comment: *all i get is "Unknown error 1451" without any additional information.* Check the daemon executable contains this error message (search for some message substring, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row', for example)... maybe it is damaged?

Comment: This is the message i get even when using through SQL yog, is there any mysql server configuration to throw additional exceptions? because for all errors even if a column is not found all i get is "unknown error" followed by "xxx code"

Comment: *when using through SQL yog* Does you mean the console client? Additionally look in Error Log...

Comment: yes and there is no error log just a single message "Unknown error 1451"

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer through this post [MySQL 5.7 No Longer Returns Meaningful Error Messages](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123105/mysql-5-7-no-longer-returns-meaningful-error-messages).
On analyzing the mysql log in the path /var/log/mysqld.log. the error was decribed as [ERROR] Can't find error-message file '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.